# Android device compatiabity issue

Tags: android, permissions, sensors

I have an app which uses magnetic sensors. But i didn't use any permission in manifest file. My question is, when i publish the app on play store, is the app filters the devices which do not have magnetic sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you do not specifically mention a particular sensor in your manifest, the Play Store will do no filtering based on the available sensors. The Play Store will only perform filtering based on the contents of your application's manifest.

You likely want to add a [`<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) element to your manifest. There is a table of available features near the bottom of the page. I am not sure from your question, but you may be looking for `android.hardware.sensor.compass`, which is the magnetometer.